# Xamarin HttpClient stuck and does not return control

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, async-await

I can't understand why the main thread doesn't give back control to process the result.

```cs
public partial class NewTravelPage : ContentPage
    {
        public NewTravelPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
            var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync();

            var vanues = await VenueLogic.getVenues(position.Latitude, position.Longitude);
            venueListView.ItemsSource = vanues;

        }
    }
```

I call the method getVenues:

```cs
public class VenueLogic
    {
        public async static Task<List<Venue>> getVenues(double latitude, double longitude)
        {
            List<Venue> vanues = new List<Venue>();

            var url = VenueRoot.GenerateUrl(latitude, longitude);

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var res = await client.GetAsync("https://stackoverflow.com"); 
                // here the code gives control to the main thread and stucks

                var response = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                var venueRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VenueRoot> 
                                                                (response);

                vanues = venueRoot.response.venues as List<Venue>;
            }

            return vanues;
        }
    }
```

Used .NetStandard; 
Please, help! I can't understand where the deadlock happens
[image]

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on `var response = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`, does it hit that breakpoint?

Comment: @mjwills No. After the line `var res = await client.GetAsync ("https://stackoverflow.com")` it gives control to the emulator and does not return to the flow of this task

Comment: I'd check for a timeout exception - set a small timeout value on the request and catch any exceptions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `async void` on a non event handler means your fire and forget call will not be able to catch any exceptions that may have been thrown.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Fix that by using an event handler

```
public partial class NewTravelPage : ContentPage {
    public NewTravelPage() {
        InitializeComponent();
        appearing += onAppearing;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing() {
        appearing(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    event EventHandler appearing = delegate { };

    private async void onAppearing(object sender, EventArgs args) {
        try {
            var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
            var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync();

            var vanues = await VenueLogic.getVenues(position.Latitude, position.Longitude);
            venueListView.ItemsSource = vanues;
        } catch( Exception ex) {
            //handler error (Log?)
        }
    }
}
```

Which would help in catching any exception to identify any problems.

Next, Referencing [You're using HttpClient wrong](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

```
public class VenueLogic {
    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public async static Task<List<Venue>> getVenues(double latitude, double longitude) {
        var url = VenueRoot.GenerateUrl(latitude, longitude);
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        var jsonContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var venueRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VenueRoot>(jsonContent);
        List<Venue> vanues = venueRoot.response.venues as List<Venue>;
        return vanues;
    }
}
```

create a single client and use that for the lifetime of the application.

Finally I would suggest you look into using Dependency injection to inject service instances where needed instead of using those static helpers

Reference [Explicit Dependencies Principle](https://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/)